# Floating point formating based on paramater?

Tags: python-3.x, parameters, formatting

How do I can have parametrized formatting ... I can do this :

```
 f' val: {val:.2f}'
```

I want to be able to do :

```
 F = 2 or 3
 f' val: {val:.Ff}'
```

how do I do that

Answer (score 0):

quantize() method rounds to a fixed number of decimal places.

Visit Decimal FAQ:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html

This may answer your question.